# Calls to LAPACK drivers from C++ crashes without error code

Tags: c++, lapack

I'm having problems calling LAPACK drivers from C++.
The following is a simple piece of code that calls dgesv, taken from:
http://www.cs.rochester.edu/~bh/cs400/using_lapack.html with minor tweaks. The code compiles without any warnings/errors but crashes without reporting any errors when I run it. Of note, if I comment out the call to dgesv, the code runs to completion.

I've tried a few pre-compiled LAPACK & BLAS libraries for Windows 64-bit and I'm getting the same behavior. I've also tried compiling the libraries from source and I got the same behavior.

I'm compiling this using MinGW64's g++ in Eclipse on a Windows 10 64bit machine.
Please help!

```
#include <cstdio>

typedef int custom_int;

extern "C" void dgesv_(const custom_int *N, const custom_int *nrhs, double *A, const custom_int *lda, custom_int* ipiv, double *b, const custom_int *ldb, custom_int *info);

int main () {
    // *********************************************************
    //  Testing basic linear algebra operations...
    // *********************************************************
    /* 3x3 matrix A
     * 76 25 11
     * 27 89 51
     * 18 60 32
     */
    double A[9] = {76, 27, 18, 25, 89, 60, 11, 51, 32};
    double b[3] = {10, 7, 43};

    custom_int N = 3;
    custom_int num_rhs = 1;
    custom_int lda = 3;
    custom_int ipiv[3];
    custom_int ldb = 3;
    custom_int info;


    // call lapack linear systems of equation solver...
    dgesv_(&N, &num_rhs, A, &lda, ipiv, b, &ldb, &info);

    //print results
    printf("\n");
    if(info == 0) /* succeed */
        printf("The solution is %lf %lf %lf\n", b[0], b[1], b[2]);
    else
        printf("dgesv fails %d\n", info);

    return 0;
}
```

Here's what i'm seeing from the debugger console:

```
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-w64-mingw32".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word".
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
No symbol table is loaded.  Use the "file" command.
[New Thread 8748.0x19cc]
[New Thread 8748.0x12b4]
[New Thread 8748.0x17a0]
[New Thread 8748.0x1568]
[Thread 8748.0x12b4 exited with code 3221225781]
[Thread 8748.0x1568 exited with code 3221225781]
```

Comment: What does your debugger tell you?

Comment: I recommend you use lapacke, the official C interface, instead of those underscore hacks.

Comment: @JesperJuhl i've updated my question with the debugger output.

Comment: @BaummitAugen i've give LAPACKE a try also.

Comment: @Lun *That* is not very useful. Do a debug build without optimization and *with* debug symbols. Then run the application from within the debugger and see what it says - and get a stacktrace after the crash so you can see where in your code things go down hill, then inspect local variables and other state to determine the cause (or re-run with a breakpoint before the crash and single step through the program and keep an eye on how state changes and compare to what you expect). You know; the usual first *basic debugging* steps.

Comment: @JesperJuhl unfortunately, i'm not very experienced with debugging c++. I'll poke around a bit and see what I can find. Thanks for the suggestion.